# Can you use in-place operators with the Python 3.8 "Walrus" operator?

Tags: python, syntax

In Python 3.8, the Walrus operator was introduced, allowing assignment as an expression.

This means we can replace these 2 statements

```
a = 2
print(a)
```

with

```
print(a := 2)
```

However, Python also has "in-place" assignment with operators where, for example, `a = a * 3` is equivalent to `a *= 3`

Is there any way to use "in-place" operator assignment, in combination with Walrus assignment?

For the following code

```py
a *= 3
print(a)
```

To re-create this with Walrus assignment, it seems you must do

```py
print(a := a * 3)
```

Both of these attempts raise a `SyntaxError`

```
print(a :*= 3)
print(a *:= 3)
```

Comment: Shorthand assignment expressions are not a thing (yet).

Comment: I guess your experiment aswered your question with a "no".

Comment: @KlausD. It seems so. I concluded there's no obvious way to do this in the latest version of Python, but I may have missed something.  Or perhaps this feature is planned for a future release.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, [augmented assignment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmented_assignment) (what you call "in-place" assignment, which doesn't always occur) is not supported with Python's Walrus operator, as stated in the specification [PEP-0572](https://peps.python.org/pep-0572/#differences-between-assignment-expressions-and-assignment-statements).

The "equivalent" (quotes with emphasis) of

> y ?= x

where `?` is a supported symbol (e.g. `+, -, *, >>, <<`,...) is

> (y := y ? x)

This is unfortunate from the perspective of programmers coming from C/C++ that have learned to appreciate that assignment expressions such as (which in C/C++ are valid not only as stand-alone statements as in Python, but as the loop condition or just about anywhere where a value can be substituted, assuming appropriate types)

> (y ?= x)

which can make code more concise and perhaps more efficient by telling the compiler to do in-place assignment if they can (in C/C++, `p++` and `++p` -- analagous to `p += 1` -- which both increment p in-place, are also idiomatic in loop conditions, stand-alone statements or just about anywhere where the (before-increment) value of p or its incremented value is needed).

Still, the Walrus operator at least helps make code more concise and readable in some situations.

```
def logb2(n: int):
    "return the (bit) position of the most significant bit of n"
    result = 0
    while (n := n >> 1):
        result += 1
    return result
```

which I prefer over something like

```
def logb2(n: int):
    result = 0
    while True: 
        n >>= 1 
        if n:
            result += 1 
        else:
            return result
```

On my hardware and software, `timeit.timeit` shows that they take about the same amount of time, with the latter performing slightly (though negligibly, negligibly) better, despite the former requiring about 3 less bytecode instructions (less bytecote instructions does not necessarily imply more efficient of course).

There are many good use cases of the Walrus operator though in my view it is most beneficial in situations where it improves readability.

Support for what you (we) are after CAN be implemented in Python, but I don't see this happening anytime soon, if ever (which, well, is not such a bad thing).

Answer (score 0):

You can't use in-place operators with the walrus operator.

Explanation :

The walrus operator assign a value to a **new** variable and return its value.

In-place operators are shortcuts to apply operators to an **existing** variable and update the variable.
In-place operators would have no meaning for a **new** variable. They raise an error if they are applied to a variable that is not assigned yet.

Therefore combining in-place and walrus has no use case.

Edit: A more practical explanation :

what would be the meaning of `a:+=1`  ?
if `a` doesn't exists, to what value `1` would be added ?
what would be the final value of `a` ?

for reference :

```
a:=8 #means : assign 8 to a and "return" a 
a+=1 #means : a = a +1 and it raises an exception if a doesn't exists
```

Comment: In python, assigning a new variable, and re-assigning an existing one, both use the same exact syntax as they are the same operation.  The walrus operator is a valid replacement in both cases.

Comment: you missed the point. 1/ if you assigning a new variable, you don't need to modify its value in-place. 2/ if you want to modify a variable in-place, you don't new assignment. 3/ Because of 1/ and 2/ , you never need in-place and walrus at the same time.

Comment: try to find an example where you would need in-place and walrus at the same time.

Comment: The functionality of the walrus operator is arguably never truly necessitated, even in cases of new assignment, hence it's late addition to Python and absence from many general purpose languages.  Perhaps the purpose of my question was not clear:  I am simply asking if this combination is at all possible in the language, as I was curious about this new language feature and how it interacts with existing assignment syntax

Comment: Walrus is truly useful but that is another discussion. I believe I correctly understood your question about combining walrus and in-place operators ; my answer is that there is no use-cases for combining them and that it can't be done in python. If you think my answer is not clear or not convincing, I would be happy to improve it using your feedbacks.

Answer (score -2):

You need to define `a` first:

`print((a := 2)*3)`

6

Comment: This does not look like it answers the question asked.

Comment: This prints 6, but `a` still holds 2.